# Setting up wifi on CLI image

Tags: command-line, wireless

I am using Ubuntu 22.04, I want to setup WiFi via USB on a base image(command line) version of the system.

A lot of the networking packages appear to not be installed and I do not have access to an Ethernet connection.

I do see the device under ls /sys/class/net

Comment: Sorry, 22.04 it is

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `ip a` (Only post the wireless interface details, likely wlx-something) and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I got it working, I used the netplan program

Comment: @FourierFlux Feel free to answer your own question, and provide details about which commands you ran exactly.